# How to Count unique values in a column of a datagridview?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

I need to count the rows of a column except the duplicate ones

House Number
123
124
11
12
11
11

Total House Number: 4

I have searched and can't find the right syntax for my code.
I tried dictionary but it seems that it is not right for my code.

I am a complete beginner in c#

```
                //Total House
            int House = 0;
            for (int row = 0; row < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; ++row)
            {
                if ((string)dataGridView1.Rows.[row].Cells("House_Number").Distinct())
                {
                    House++;
                }
            }

            TotalHouse.Text = "Total Houses   " + $"{House}";
```

I tried the above code but it has an error Identifier expected.

Comment: `.Distinct()` is probably not right for your loop code either.  Start with the error code.  Read it carefully.  Focus on that and only that until it is fixed, then see if the code you wrote is doing anything close to what you want.  What is `...Cells("House_Number")` supposed to be? Is `Cells` a collection or a method?

Answer (score 1):

Your code has a few potential problems, but let's start with the ones that will prevent it from compiling.

```
if ((string)dataGridView1.Rows.[row].Cells("House_Number").Distinct())
```

One problematic bit here is `Rows.[row]`.  There shouldn't be a period there.  If you have a period like that, C# will expect an identifier to follow it, not another operator.  In this case, you have the `[]` operator following it, which is invalid.  It should probably look like this:

```
if ((string)dataGridView1.Rows[row].Cells("House_Number").Distinct())
```

We're getting closer.  However, the test inside an `if` statement must evaluate to a `bool`--that's `true` or `false`.  Yours evaluates to a `string` because you're casting the whole thing to a string.  That's because this part runs first:

```
dataGridView1.Rows[row].Cells("House_Number").Distinct()
```

Then this part runs:

```
(string)
```

So the whole thing becomes a string.  We'll have to remove that `(string)` bit.

Let's take a closer look at `dataGridView1.Rows[row].Cells("House_Number").Distinct()`.  `Cells` isn't a method--[it's a property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrow.cells?view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_Forms_DataGridViewRow_Cells).  That means you can't use the syntax `Cells("House_Number")`.  However, the result of `Cells` is a `DataGridViewCellCollection`, which allows `[]` syntax, so you can do something like `Cells["House_Number"]`.

`Distinct()` isn't going to give you a `bool` value--it will give you a collection of unique cells in the form of something called an `IEnumerable`.

`dataGridView1.Rows[row].Cells.Distinct()` isn't going to give you distinct cells in a column--it's going to give you distinct cells in a row.  That's probably not what you want.

You're probably going to want something that looks like this:

```
int houses = dataGridView1.Rows
    .Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
    .Select(r => (int)r.Cells["House_Number"].Value)
    .Distinct()
    .Count();
```

Walking through this:

1. Start with `dataGridView1`.
2. Get a `DataGridViewCellCollection` of rows: `.Rows`
3. `DataGridViewCellCollection` is pretty old, so it implements `IEnumerable` instead of `IEnumerable<DataGridViewRow>`.  We need to turn it into an `IEnumerable<DataGridViewRow>`, so we call LINQ's `Cast<DataGridViewRow>()`.
4. Use LINQ to turn that into an `IEnumerable<int>`: `.Select(r => (int)r.Cells["House_Number"].Value)`
   a. The argument to `Select` is a lambda expression.  It takes one argument, `r`, which is a `DataGridViewRow`.  It will return an `int`.
   b. Get the cells for the row: `.Cells`
   c. Get the specific cell we want: `["House_Number"]`
   d. Get the value of that cell
   e. The value is returned as an `object`; we need to cast it to an int: `(int)`
5. Use LINQ to turn that `IEnumerable<int>` into another one that only has distinct values: `.Distinct()`
6. Count our results: `.Count()`

You'll need a reference to `System.Linq` for this to work.  Put this at the top of your file if it isn't already there:

```
using System.Linq;
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation, I will look into IEnumerable more..
going back to my code now it gives an error "Specified cast is not valid

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this easily by adding a nuget reference to `System.Data.DataSetExtensions`

and then using linq to select the distinct house numbers:

`var count = dataGridView1.AsEnumerable().Select(dr => dr["House_Number"]).Distinct().Count();`

Otherwise you could achieve this using a hashset:

```
var hs = new HashSet<string>();

foreach (DataRow dataRow in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    hs.Add(dataRow["House_Number"].ToString());
}

TotalHouse.Text = "Total Houses   " + $"{hs.Count}";
```